# Failing to import SQLAlchemy and Pymysql into AWS Glue Python Shell script

Tags: sqlalchemy, aws-glue, pymysql, python-wheel

I have a Python script which imported 3 libraries:

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

I'm planning to run Python Shell on AWS Glue. Following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html) doc pages, I created a `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="pylibmodule",
      version="0.1",
      packages=[],
      install_requires=['sqlalchemy==1.3.9','pandas==0.25.3','pymysql==0.9.3']
  )
```

I ran `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, put the resulting `pylibmodule-0.1-py3-none-any.whl` file into an S3 bucket, and then specified the bucket location in the Glue Job setting. When I ran the job script, it produced an error.

After an investigation, I found that I have sucessfully imported the pandas module, but failed to import sqlalchemy and pymysql.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as per the document, i think import should be from the named module? i.e.,can you try "from pylibmodule import sqlalchemy" instead of "import sqlalchemy".  Also i hope your python script is in the same folder as the whl files? (As per point#4)

Answer (score 1):

I ran the job again this morning without changing anything in the setting and the script. It suddenly works. I think the error I received last night was due to some cache residue on Glue's end.